# Hydra combine lists in config

Tags: python, fb-hydra, omegaconf

Say I have the following hydra config `test.yaml`:

```yaml
list1 : [0]
list2 : [1,2,3]
```

is it possible to merge `list1` and `list2` into a new list that contains `[0,1,2,3]`, perhaps using variable interpolation?

Here is the hydra code:

```py
import hydra
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
@hydra.main(config_name="test.yaml", config_path="./")
def main(cfg):
    OmegaConf.resolve(cfg)
    print(cfg)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Attempt (failed):

```yaml
list1 : [0]
list2 : [1,2,3]
list3 : 
  - ${list1} 
  - ${list2}
```

`list3` gives `[0,[1,2,3]]`

The reason I want this is because I have some lists of unknown length in other config files and want to merge them to create an argument for object creation. I'd prefer not to do this in the code and just rely directly on hydras object instantiation (otherwise I'll be doing list merging everywhere!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is not too difficult, one can indeed rely on OmegaConfs variable interpolation with a custom resolver.

```py
import hydra
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
# custom list merge resolver
OmegaConf.register_new_resolver("merge", lambda x, y : x + y)

@hydra.main(config_name="test.yaml", config_path="./")
def main(cfg):
    OmegaConf.resolve(cfg)
    print(cfg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Config file `test.yaml`

```yaml
list1 : [0]
list2 : [1,2,3]

list3 : ${merge:${list1},${list2}}
```

`list3` is now `[0,1,2,3]` as desired.

Comment: Yup, this is the right way to do it.