How to correctly do consolde overwrites for hydra
I have a yaml file
cars:
  - model: "Sedan"
    length: 4.5
    width: 1.8
    height: 1.4
    fuel_efficiency: 
    - 12  # City
    - 15  # Highway
    - 13  # Combined
  - model: "SUV"
    length: 4.8
    width: 2.0
    height: 1.7
    fuel_efficiency: 
    - 10
    - 12
    - 11
  - model: Hatchback
    length: 4.0
    width: 1.7
    height: 1.4
    fuel_efficiency:
    - 14
    - 18
    - 16

I have written a script using Hydra that contains the following
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig

@hydra.main(config_path="config", config_name="car_data", version_base=None)
def main(cfg:DictConfig):
    for car in cfg.cars:
        print(car.model)

I get the values, do some calculation and everything goes alright!
My question is how can I do consolde overwrites of some values ( a feature of Hydra)
I have tried
>python process_cars.py cars[0].length=4.8
LexerNoViableAltException: cars[0].length=4.8
                               ^
See https://hydra.cc/docs/1.2/advanced/override_grammar/basic for details

I tried reading the suggested doc, but can not figure it out how to apply in this case

Maybe try dot notation with a number, like: python process_cars.py cars.0.length=4.8

@Vile Great! It worked! And how about if I want to change the fuel_efficiency to another array?

I'm not certain, but try something like python process_cars.py cars.0.fuel_efficiency=cars.1.fuel_efficiency
Also, this might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527303/hydra-combine-lists-in-config

The issue is with the syntax for accessing list elements in Hydra's override grammar. For lists, you need to use dot notation with a number, rather than square bracket notation. Here's how to correctly override the values:
python process_cars.py cars.0.length=4.8
Some more examples of valid Hydra overrides for your config:
# Change multiple properties of the first car
python process_cars.py cars.0.length=4.8 cars.0.width=2.0

# Change fuel efficiency values (since it's a nested list)
python process_cars.py cars.0.fuel_efficiency.0=13 cars.0.fuel_efficiency.1=16

# Change values for multiple cars
python process_cars.py cars.0.model=Coupe cars.1.height=1.8

# Change an entire fuel efficiency array
python process_cars.py cars.0.fuel_efficiency=[15,18,16]

As for overriding an entire array in Hydra, here are a few ways to do it:
# Method 1: Using square brackets
python process_cars.py cars.0.fuel_efficiency=[20,25,22]

# Method 2: If you prefer comma-separated without spaces
python process_cars.py cars.0.fuel_efficiency=[20\,25\,22]

You can also combine this with other overrides:
python process_cars.py cars.0.fuel_efficiency=[20,25,22] cars.0.length=4.8

